# Trying to make a map

Tags: android

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

"For some odd reason the area that says .getmap() isnt working. can anyone help."

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .getmap() part and putting getMapAsync() instead.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but its saying theat (This) is an error in the coding.